# Run a python script in the guest virtual machine using vmrun runScriptInGuest

Tags: python, vmware, vmware-fusion

I am trying to run a very long python script which resides in guest virtual machine A.py from the host linux machine. The guest VM is Windows 7x64 and application is VMware Fusion.

I am using following command:

```
vmrun -T ws -gu <username> -gp <password> runScriptInGuest "/Users/userdir/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows7x64.vmwarevm/Windows7x64.vmx" C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\A.py C:\Python27\python.exe
```

This is not working. Any ideas on how to get this working?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but try changing the order of the last 2 arguments:

```
vmrun -T ws -gu -gp runScriptInGuest "/Users/userdir/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows7x64.vmwarevm/Windows7x64.vmx" C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Admin\Documents\A.py
```

The Python interpreter should be invoked by the VM and the interpreter will run the `A.py` script.

Comment: Please add -activeWindow flag as shown in Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
vmrun -T ws -gu Admin -gp Apple1984 runProgramInGuest "/Users/userdir/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows7x64.vmwarevm/Windows7x64.vmx" -activeWindow "C:\Users\\Admin\A.bat"
```

where A.bat is a bat file where I invoke python script

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Admin
C:\python27\python.exe A.py %*
```

Comment: This is fundamentally the same as my suggested solution, I wonder why you chose to unaccept?

Comment: Because the flag -activeWindow was necessary. I can reselect your answer. No issues.

Answer (score 0):

try the pip module. [vmrunPacked](https://pypi.org/project/vmrunPacked/) this pkg use to vm take control. start, stop, snapshot create, revert, delete. inside file run. both of all execute.

**vmrunPacked** tool use run the **A.py** script

`pip install vmrunPacked`

install this package

```py
import vmrunPacked
#assgin vm object
vmobj = vmrunPacked.Pack("/vmx_file_path/vm.vmx",userName="admin",passWord="admin@123")

# start the vm
vmobj.start()

# run the ruby script file in inside vm
interpreter_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Ruby\\ruby.exe"
file_path = "D:\\new\\init.rb"
vmobj.run_script_in_guest(interpreter_path, file_path)
```

read the document [vmrunPacked](https://pypi.org/project/vmrunPacked/)